# Visual Captcha implementation with Java /Struts/Spring project

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, user-interface, captcha

I am new to UI development. I need some guidance related to implementing visual captcha with a Java project that uses Struts/Spring javascript/JQuery. Can anyone please provide some info about it? or Any mock project

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google's Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)